# Hidden speech bubbles CSS effect underneath other boxes

Tags: html, css, image, css-transitions, behind

I am an illustrator building my first portfolio website.

To annotate my illustrations I am having hidden speech bubbles with text appear when you hover over an image this can be seen in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmorrell2014/v6Bkk/9/) (the first two blocks)

However the speech bubbles are always underneath the images bellow them.

The images bellow also have a CSS affect on that enlarges them and I am not to sure if this could be affecting the speech bubble class in any way.

If someone could point out to me the code which I am missing to make the speech bubbles appear on top of everything it would be really helpful!

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper2">

<div id="container"><a href="#" class="hoverbubble">Hover over me!<span>Hidden message here. Hidden message here. Hidden message here. Hidden message here. Hidden message here.Hidden message here. Hidden message here.Hidden message here.Hidden message here.</span></a></div>

<div id="container"><a href="#" class="hoverbubble"><img src="http://placekitten.com/180/160" class="hoverbubble"/><span>Hidden message here. Hidden message here. Hidden message here. Hidden message here. Hidden message here.Hidden message here. Hidden message here.Hidden message here.Hidden message here.</span></a></div>

 <div id="bottem"><div class="scale scaleMe" id="container"></div><div class="scale scaleMe" id="container"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS for class "hoverbubble"

```
a.hoverbubble {
text-decoration: none;
}
a.hoverbubble span {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
top: 40%;
}
a.hoverbubble:hover span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: attr(title);
min-width: px;
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
top: 180px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
}
a.hoverbubble:hover span:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
content: "";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 120px;
left: 90px;
border-top-width: 10px;
border-right-width: 10px;
border-bottom-width: 10px;
border-left-width: 10px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: transparent;
border-right-color: transparent;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

CSS for class "scale"

```
.scale {
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
-o-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;   
}
.scaleMe:hover {
transform: scale(1.2);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
-o-transform: scale(1.2);
-moz-transform: scale(1.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
-o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `z-index: 5` to `a.hoverbubble:hover span`

Comment: Correct but the z-index doesn't need to be anywhere near that high, a value of `1` will do it.